# By default, do DRF viewsets allow PUT, PARTIAL_UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, LIST and RETRIEVE?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

Suppose I create this viewset:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'username'
```

and this router:

```
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
```

and this serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email')
```

Is there documentation that mentions if, by default, it does or does not allow `user` accept `PUT`, `PARTIAL_UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `LIST` and `CREATE` requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mapping is explained in the [router's documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to make it so that the Viewset does not accept put or destroy requests? (My current way of doing it is creating a permissions `NoPut` and `NoDestroy` which returns `False` if the action is `put`or `destroy`.

Comment: Yup, you need to herit from GenericViewSet and add the mixin you want to implement (mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin)